# Error when uploading/viewing certain pictures - rendition not found - django storages/ wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Wagtail version: 2.9.2
Django storages: ==1.11.1

Error:

```
 2021-06-07 14:13:12 ERROR Internal Server Error: /admin/images/38/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/images/models.py", line 300, in get_rendition
     focal_point_key=cache_key,
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in get
     self.model._meta.object_name
 wagtail.images.models.Rendition.DoesNotExist: Rendition matching query does not exist.
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
     return self.get(**kwargs), False
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in get
     self.model._meta.object_name
 wagtail.images.models.Rendition.DoesNotExist: Rendition matching query does not exist.
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
     response = response.render()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
     self.content = self.rendered_content
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
     return template.render(context, self._request)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
     return self.template.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
     return self._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
     return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
     return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
     return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
     return nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
     return template.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
     return self._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
     return template.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
     return self._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
     return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/images/templatetags/wagtailimages_tags.py", line 107, in render
     rendition = get_rendition_or_not_found(image, self.filter)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/images/shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_rendition_or_not_found
     return image.get_rendition(specs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/images/models.py", line 329, in get_rendition
     defaults={'file': File(generated_image.f, name=output_filename)}
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 682, in get_or_create
     return super(RelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).get_or_create(**kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 562, in get_or_create
     return self._create_object_from_params(kwargs, params)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 596, in _create_object_from_params
     obj = self.create(**params)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 749, in save
     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 787, in save_base
     force_update, using, update_fields,
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 890, in _save_table
     results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 929, in _do_insert
     using=using, raw=raw,
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1393, in execute_sql
     for sql, params in self.as_sql():
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1338, in as_sql
     for obj in self.query.objs
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1338, in <listcomp>
     for obj in self.query.objs
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1337, in <listcomp>
     [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1288, in pre_save_val
     return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 288, in pre_save
     file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 87, in save
     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 52, in save
     return self._save(name, content)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/dropbox.py", line 139, in _save
     self.client.files_upload(content.read(), self._full_path(name), mode=WriteMode(self.write_mode))
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stone/backends/python_rsrc/stone_base.py", line 141, in __init__
     assert validator is not None, 'Invalid tag %r.' % tag
 AssertionError: Invalid tag True.
```

Cause:

Viewing images in the image panel, uploading images etc. only certain images though, and website loads perfectly fine, this suddenly stopped working, not sure when.

Some renditions definitely exist on dropbox, there's still space, and API key works for sure, other images work, only a bunch of more recent ones doesn't:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Turns out django-storages had an update where DROPBOX_WRITE_MODE was added, or maybe it's behaviour changed, i had this line in the settigns.py file:

```
DROPBOX_WRITE_MODE = True
```

instead of:

```
DROPBOX_WRITE_MODE = "add"
```

which triggered an error when dropbox storages attempted writing anything to dropbox, but reading worked